# Lightning Web Component -- Lightning bundles must have a parent folder named ! 'lightningcomponents'

Tags: visualstudiocode, lightning-web-components

I am trying to create Lightning web component and keep getting this message, but could not figure out the issue. What does it say?

```
Starting SFDX: Create Lightning Web Component

23:59:38.741 sfdx force:lightning:component:create --type lwc --componentname firstwebcomponent --outputdir force-app\main\default\lwc
 !    !   Lightning bundles must have a parent folder named
 !    'lightningcomponents'.
23:59:50.333 sfdx force:lightning:component:create --type lwc --componentname firstwebcomponent --outputdir force-app\main\default\lwc ended with exit code 1
```

[image]

Comment: What is your cli version ? Run sfdx plugins in your terminal

Comment: And you need pre release version of the plug-in for it

Comment: @MohithShrivastava Thanks it works after updating the version.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lets understand how the vscode extension for lwc works . Vscode extension invokes the CLI commands that the salesforcedx cli plugin provides .

In pilot release lwc folder was named as lightningwebcomponent and not lwc and hence prior cli version still use the same old reference .

Get the pre-release cli plugin by running `sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release`

and when you run `sfdx plugins` you will see v45.0.xx if you have the latest cli .Now when you try creating an lwc component you should be fine .

Comment: Your answer explains the exact reason behind my problem.

Comment: Thanks @MohithShrivastava. :) This works.

Answer (score 1):

From below link

https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=9063A000000Dz9xQAC

Please execute the below commands: -

1 - sfdx plugins --core

2 - sfdx plugins:install salesforcedx@pre-release

3 - again execute sfdx plugins --core

For more information see the below video

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dcRM7Mq541Y&t=1798s

Comment: Can you explain further? It is not clear to me. I have not created LWC yet. while trying to create, I am getting that message. I am adding a screenshot for more information.

Comment: @sfdc Please correct the typo. It should be "install" for point 2.